How to get page number correctly from azure ai search index when run the azure open ai model?
I upload my document ( a pdf file) to Azure blob storage. Then I use Azure AI Search to import and vectorize the file, and it create an search index. When I run the Azure open AI model on VS code, which connect and retrieve this search index. I choose to return the citations for the retrieved document.
The code I write for azure open ai model:
Python
def main():
    
    try:
        show_citations = True

        load_dotenv()
        azure_oai_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_ENDPOINT")
        azure_oai_key = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_KEY")
        azure_oai_deployment = os.getenv("AZURE_OAI_DEPLOYMENT")
        azure_search_endpoint = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT")
        azure_search_key = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_KEY")
        azure_search_index = os.getenv("AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX")
              
        client = AzureOpenAI(
            azure_endpoint=azure_oai_endpoint,
            api_key=azure_oai_key,
            api_version="2024-05-01-preview",
        )

        #Get the prompt
        text= input('\nEnter a question:\n')       
        completion = client.chat.completions.create(
            model=azure_oai_deployment,
            messages= [
            {
              "role": "user",
              "content": text
            }],
            max_tokens=800,
            temperature=0.7,
            top_p=0.95,
            frequency_penalty=0,
            presence_penalty=0,
            stop=None,
            stream=False,
            extra_body={
              "data_sources": [{
                  "type": "azure_search",
                  "parameters": {
                    "endpoint": f"{azure_search_endpoint}",
                    "index_name": "test-index",
                    "semantic_configuration": "default",
                    "query_type": "vector_semantic_hybrid",
                    #"query_type": "semantic",
                    "fields_mapping": {
                      "content_fields_separator": "\n",
                      "content_fields": [
                        "content"
                      ],
                      "filepath_field": "chunk_id",
                      "title_field": "title",
                      "url_field": "url",
                      "vector_fields": [
                        "contentVector"
                      ]
                    },
                    "in_scope": True,
                    "role_information": "You are a helpful for finding information",
                    "filter": None,
                    "strictness": 3,
                    "top_n_documents": 5,
                    "authentication": {
                      "type": "api_key",
                      "key": f"{azure_search_key}"                                                                                                                                                      
                    },
                    "embedding_dependency": {
                      "type": "deployment_name",
                      "deployment_name": "text-embedding-ada-002"
                    }
                  }
                }]
            }
        )

I can see the page number at the end of chunk_id in the citation like below:
Chunk ID: 0ffd977ce09f_aHR0cHM6Ly9hbmh0cmFpbnN0b3JhZ2VhY2NvdW50LmJsb2IuY29yZS53aW5kb3dzLm5ldC9maWxldXBsb2FkLXRlc3QtaW5kZXgvQmx1ZV9aZWJyYV9MYW5kbG9yZF9JbnN1cmFuY2VfQWNjaWRlbnRhbF9EYW1hZ2VfUERTXzIwMjMwNzAxLnBkZg2_pages_19
However, when I check the content of these chunks with pdf file, the page number is not correct for some chunks. For example, chunk content is in page 11 but the number in chunk id is in page 20.
Therefore, do you know any way/ skills to extract the page number separately from chunkid and the page number is correct with the content in the pdf file. I want to return the page number correctly in the citation.
Thank you ,
I want to return the page number correctly in the citation.

Add your search index, indexer, skillset definition

Probably the issue is how you're chunking your files. If you can chunk by page, it should work.

@user3503711  I just uploaded whole file and Azure AI search chunk/split the file automatically. I ticked the option using vectorize model by Azure Open AI embedding model. Therefore, the search index creates all citations ( path, title, chunk_id by itself).

@Anna If its automatically doing the chunks, then it wouldn't be per page (i,e, page 17 = chunk 17). If you still want that, you might need to write your own code - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/vector-search-how-to-chunk-documents
